# Unexpected identifier Jest Vue SVG

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I've had this error during running jest on my Vue. I run `jest` command, and get the error below.

If I remove the `svg` element in the component. It's working fine

**Error message**

```
 FAIL  test/Header.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jakzaizzat/Code/taiger/kwa/kcp-admin-ui/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _Object$defineProperty from "../../core-js/object/define-property";
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      19 |             />
      20 |             <path
    > 21 |               d="M15.9999 0L0 8.5541V8.77758V27.0448L16.0001 35.5984L32 27.045V8.5541L15.9999 0ZM16.4239 25.007L18.6367 26.3025L21.1325 24.9877L21.5461 25.7729L18.614 27.3176L15.9848 25.7781L13.3554 27.3176L10.4233 25.7729L10.8369 24.9877L13.3325 26.3025L15.5364 25.0122L15.5358 22.9129L10.7279 19.9154V16.1301L4.71654 13.6018L5.06044 12.7836L11.6154 15.5405V19.1554H20.353V15.5405L26.908 12.7836L27.2519 13.6018L21.2407 16.1301V19.9155L16.4231 22.9197L16.4239 25.007Z"
         |                                               ^
      22 |               fill="white"
      23 |             />
      24 |           </svg>
```

**Header.spec.js**

```
import Header from "../src/components/shared/Card.vue";
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils";

describe('Header.vue', () => {
    test('render header navigation', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Header);
        expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
    });
});
```

**Header.vue**

```
<div class="px-4">
        <router-link
          to="/"
          class="logo"
        >
          <svg
            width="32"
            height="36"
            viewBox="0 0 32 36"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M15.9849 22.1472L19.3588 20.043H12.6101L15.9849 22.1472Z"
              fill="white"
            />
            <path
              d="M15.9999 0L0 8.5541V8.77758V27.0448L16.0001 35.5984L32 27.045V8.5541L15.9999 0ZM16.4239 25.007L18.6367 26.3025L21.1325 24.9877L21.5461 25.7729L18.614 27.3176L15.9848 25.7781L13.3554 27.3176L10.4233 25.7729L10.8369 24.9877L13.3325 26.3025L15.5364 25.0122L15.5358 22.9129L10.7279 19.9154V16.1301L4.71654 13.6018L5.06044 12.7836L11.6154 15.5405V19.1554H20.353V15.5405L26.908 12.7836L27.2519 13.6018L21.2407 16.1301V19.9155L16.4231 22.9197L16.4239 25.007Z"
              fill="white"
            />
          </svg>
        </router-link>
      </div>
```

Any idea what is the cause of this issue?

Comment: Are you running `jest` directly from the command line? Or are you using Vue CLI's npm script (`npm run test:unit`)?

Comment: @tony19 I'm using a `jest` command

Comment: Vue CLI sets up `jest` for you, so you'd be missing that configuration when running `jest` directly.

Comment: @tony19 Seems like I can't run `npm run test:unit`, the command its not defined in the `package.json`

Comment: @tony19 I've updated my question with code snippet

Comment: The `test:unit` script is normally added by Vue CLI. Are you using a Vue CLI generated project?

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I need to run via `test:unit`.